# Noisy data presented in tabular form are given. Fit and build a model curve

Tags: scilab

Noisy data presented in tabular form are given. Fit and build a model curve. Choose a functional dependence of the form:

[image]

Comment: You're asking too many questions in one post. Choose one and describe it more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Scilab code for your first example, you will be able to adapt it to other cases. To evaluate the obtained polynomial `F` use Scilab function `horner` (see the associated help page by typing `help horner`).

```
gd = [1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2.1 2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 3.1]';
Fd = [1.55 2.73 3.91 5.51 7.11 9.12 11.12 12.91 15.45 17.91]';
c = [ones(gd), gd, gd.^2, gd.^3]\Fd;
F = poly(c,"g","coeff");
disp(F)
```

the above script displays

```
  7.6508968 -14.91761g +9.8440484g² -1.2735795g³
```

You can plot the graph of the polynomial and the original noisy data like this:

```
g = linspace(1.2,3.1,100);
plot(g, horner(F,g),gd,Fd,'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, can you validate if everything is clear to you ?